# Prevent Java icon from popping up in dock

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij IDEA on Mac OSX 10.9.2. Usually I have the IDE on another space, and I switch between both. The problem is that when I run something from the IDE, the Java icon pops up in the dock, switching the space automatically, so I have to switch back to the IDE each time this happens. It is really annoying.

Is there anyway to prevent this from happening? I have tried the "headless" option, but it doesn't work.

Comment: When you say another desktop, do you mean you have multiple monitors?

Comment: @mdewitt I don't have several physical monitors, only one. What I have is several desktops: I switch between them using Ctrl+arrow. I think they are called "Spaces", so will edit.

Comment: This really doesn't belong on SO as it's not a programming question. Try SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

you should try right-clicking the icon in your dock and selecting "assign to both desktops" on the icon that's bugging you...
it should do the trick

BTW, this isn't a java question , it's  a mac OSX question

Comment: Edited the question: I don't have desktops, but "spaces". That option doesn't appear in the icon either.

Comment: right click your icon->options ->assign to:

works on my mac OSx 10.9.1

Comment: facing this in 2020.  There's no assign to option.